# How to replace new line characters in a textarea with spaces

Tags: javascript, html

I've a HTML form in which I'm using JavaScript function to replace the new line characters (\n) with spaces. I'm using onClick method to call the function.

HTML form looks like something this-

```
<form action="#" method="post">
Type text here<br />
<textarea name="text" onClick="autofix();" id="textarea"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

JavaScript code looks like something this-

```
<script>
function autofix()
{
var text=document.getElementById('textarea');
var revnl=text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
text=revnl;
}
```

But it is not working! please help

Answer (score 2):

Attach to the `onkeyup` event (or `onkeydown`).

Then, replace the script with this:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
var revnl = textarea.value.replace(/\s/gm," ");
textarea.value = revnl;
```

This will replace all white-spaces (even new lines and tabs) with common spaces.

**EDIT**: for multiple textareas

You can use a closure:

```
function attachAutofix(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).onkeydown = function (ev) { // or onkeyup
        ev = ev || event;
        target = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
        target.value = target.value.replace(/\s/gm," ");
    };
}
```

Finally, attach the events:

```
window.onload = function () {
    attachAutofix("firstTextarea");
    attachAutofix("secondTextarea");
    attachAutofix("thirdTextarea");
};
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! 
What if I've multiple textarea in the form?

Comment: @Disk01 use the prop `onkeydown(this)`, then in the function receive the argument `function autofix(ta)` and use as follows: `ta.value = ta.value.replace(/\s/gm," ")`

Comment: I posted buggy code 2 minutes ago. Now it should be fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the part after the first linefeed instead, you can use this:

```
oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/\n[\s\S]*/,'')"
```

`[\s\S]` is like `.` but it matches newlines. The `//s` modifier also makes dot match newlines, but it was only added in ES2018.

BTW it's better to use `oninput` rather than `onkeyup`, because `onekeyup` is not triggered when text is entered by pasting with the mouse or by dragging and dropping. And `onkeyup` is also triggered more slowly than `oninput`, which results in a visible delay before the text gets removed.